# Extract strings from xml file using Perl

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

I need to extract the strings that are placed after **association rightmh=** using Perl.

In this example: "0x42001dc" & "0x4200000".

Each string will be added to the same array.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<association-response-list xmlns="http://url.com">
<association-responses>
<association rightmh="0x42001dc" leftmh="0x4055246" rh="0x1003b"/>
<association rightmh="0x4200000" leftmh="0x455246" rh="0x1003b"/>
</association-responses>
</association-response-list>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an XML parser, for example [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = << '__XML__';
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<association-response-list xmlns="http://url.com">
<association-responses>
<association rightmh="0x42001dc" leftmh="0x4055246" rh="0x1003b"/>
<association rightmh="0x4200000" leftmh="0x455246" rh="0x1003b"/>
</association-responses>
</association-response-list>
__XML__

my $doc = 'XML::LibXML'->load_xml(string => $xml);

my @rightmh;
push @rightmh, $_->value for $doc->findnodes('//@rightmh');
print "@rightmh\n";
```

Comment: except in this case you will get the value of `rightmh` even if it's not an attribute of `association`. Oddly enough `//association/@rightmh` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @mirod: It's because of the namespace. One has to register it and use a prefix in the XPath expressions.

Comment: @choroba yep, I was just commenting about it. God I hate default namespaces.

Comment: So the solution as posted is not actually correct

Comment: @mirod: So do I. One of the last things the next generation markup language will have to solve differently.

Comment: @choroba, It's not a problem with XML, it's a problem with XPath. If you could specify a namespace for XPaths to use by default, there'd be no problem.

Comment: for me the problem is that adding a default namespace creates action-at-distance that makes XPath queries fail. Most peope don't realize that, especially when they add the namespace to an XHTML doc.

Answer (score 3):

A solution with [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::Twig;

my $xml = << '__XML__';
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<association-response-list xmlns="http://url.com">
<association-responses>
<association rightmh="0x42001dc" leftmh="0x4055246" rh="0x1003b"/>
<association rightmh="0x4200000" leftmh="0x455246" rh="0x1003b"/>
</association-responses>
</association-response-list>
__XML__

my @rightmh;
XML::Twig->new( twig_roots => { 'association[@rightmh]'
                                   => sub { push @rightmh, $_->att( 'rightmh'); }
                              }
              )
         ->parse( $xml);
print "@rightmh\n";
```

Comment: Nitpicking: Not correct if there is `association` in a different namespace ;-)

Comment: touché! I guess a regexp solution is better then ;--)

Answer (score -2):

You can use regular expressions.

```
my @array;
open XML, "<file.xml";
while(<XML>){
 if($_ =~ /association rightmh="(.*?)"/){
  push @array, $1;
 }
}
```